# GCP: getting charged for a deleted VM. How can I delete resources individually?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I'm quite new to GCP.

Yesterday I created a VM instance and used it for around 4 hours, and deleted the VM.

The cost when I checked after deleting was around 0.07 USD. Today morning I checked the billing page and saw that the cost is now 0.59 USD. I saw that I'm being charged for "N1 Predefined Instance Core running in Americas" and "N1 Predefined Instance Ram running in Americas". I used these when creating the VM, but I thought that those resources get released automatically when deleting the VM.

[image]

I have been charged for 12.4 hours according to this. But the VM isn't even there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the numbers you show I suspect you used an n1-standard-4 VM which has 4vCPUs and 15 GB of RAM for 3.1 hours.

**N1 Predefined Instance Core running ...** bills per core, then if you run a VM with more than 1 core the *Usage* is multiplied as cores you were using.

For example:

- If you run a VM with 1 vCPU for 1 hour, in **Usage** you will see 1 hour
- If you run a VM with 2 vCPU for 1 hour, in **Usage** you will see 2 hour
- If you run a VM with 4 vCPU for 1 hour, in **Usage** you will see 4 hour
- and so on...

With the RAM is the same, for example:

- If you run a VM with 1 GB for 1 hour, in **Usage** you will see 1 GB
- If you run a VM with 2 GB for 1 hour, in **Usage** you will see 2 GB
- If you run a VM with 4 GB for 2 hour, in **Usage** you will see 8 GB
- and so on...

So, if you used the VM for 3.1 Hours and asuming it was an n1-standard-4 as mentioned at the beggining, then we have:

> 3.1 hours x 4 vCPUs = 12.4 hours
>
> 3.1 hours x 15 GB RAM = 46.5 RAM gigabyte hour

So the costs are correct. I would suggest to take a look to the [GCE pricing docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing) for more details about this and for sure using the [GCP pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) can be very helpful too.

One of my best advices I give to anyone that starts using any cloud service (AWS, GCP, Azure, etc) is to always check and understand the costs before doing anything, so there are no surprises like "I don't know where these costs came from!!!" and most important, help you to optimize your money.

Comment: I like this answer. Add a reference link to Google documentation.

Comment: Thanks! You’re right. I didn’t know that pricing is multiplied by the core count. Thanks for that information!

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the suggestion @john-hanley, I've edited my answer c: