# Avoid high daily charges with Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

So I am in a developing mode, and within 10 days of developing, I had a **300$** bill to Google.

What I did :

1. Created a test table, and added records to it - text and numbers.
2. Performed multiple queries, from my Mac, I would say **100 a day for 6 days**.
3. Have a table with around **100k rows and 6 columns**.

This is what I do for every query (does reconnecting for every query cost more?) :

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://' + username + ':' + password + '@' + host + ':' + port + '/' + database)
df = pd.read_sql_query(current_query, engine)
```

4. I am writing around 2000 rows at a time ( only me), and I was sometimes reading thousands of rows - for the development.

You can see my charges [image: here] and [image: here]

5. CPU show 1.4% constantly for 24 hours, but I do not use it all this time.

I can see a **daily** charge of **9$ for RAM and 8$ for CPU**. The charge is **constant** and daily, so it seems it is not relate to my action.

I talked with Google, and they could not explain the charge, nor you can see this on the `Console`.

What can I do to understand exactly for what action they charged me ? it seems like a daily fixed amount.

If this is how Google charge, it is scary to think how much would it cost with 10k users (or more)

Comment: Google sent me to "learn", so I am expecting to get a better idea on 1. what could cause this according to photo? is it queries? traffic?. 2. how to measure 3. how to view more deeply the charges 4. how is it that they are constant daily? 5. is this reasonable for such data?

Comment: Have you reviewed the [Cloud SQL pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing)?

Comment: yes I did. thanks you. it is very unclear, what can I assume from $0.0413 per vCPU ? I obviously had high CPU but I do not know why.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience so others of us can learn from it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cloud SQL does not charge you by the queries you perform, it charges you by the instance you use.

This is mentioned in the [Cloud SQL docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing) like @cory-kramer said:

> Cloud SQL pricing is composed of the following charges:
>
> - CPU and memory pricing
> - Storage and networking pricing
> - Instance pricing

The costs in the pricing docs are per hour per vCPU and per hour per GB of memory. Those are the double if you use HA instances.

From the screenshot, I can say you created a HA Cloud SQL instance because it says *Regional* (BTW it is not necessary to hide the SKUs, those are public and are the same for everybody).

Let's suppose you have a HA instance using Postgres with 4 vCPU and 15 GB RAM with 10 GB of disk in us-central1.

Using the [GCP Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) we get an estimate of $397.89 USD a month for just 1 instance.

Now a follow up question could be, "If I used the instance only 1 day or 2 days, the report says I used more than 24 or 48 hours".

The reason is that the vCPU is multiplied as cores the instance has. This also applies for the RAM and it is very similar to how [GCE VMs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65912121/12265927) are charged.

The formulas are:

```
cpu_hours = vCPUs * 24 hrs * days instance was active

memory_hours = RAM * 24 hrs * days instance was active
```

To avoid a lot of charges you can start/stop daily the instance or if this is a development instance you can decrease the hardware to a very little instance like 1 vCPU, 0.614 GB or the minimum necessary hardware to work. Also you can [make it zonal](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-ha#disabling_on_an_instance)(not HA)

Also the prices change depending on the regions those are created.

My advice here is to fully understand the pricing before creating resources to avoid any surprise. I understand the docs can be confusing but it's better to take the needed time to check them so you can optimize your budget.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just did a long reading, and I realized Google is super expensive for small startups, I removed the HA, I set 1vcpu, I set the 100G minimum storage SSD, still the estimator show a very high charge. I can't turn it off sometimes because it suppose to be a SaaS. Why would I want to pay that when I only start ? you build something you check an idea, you don't want to pay 100-300$ a month. Why they don't provide Firebase like Blaze plan to grow as you have more users? do they have any other service that allow Postgresql with more affordable flexible plan ?

Comment: in other words, since I struggle here, can you bring this account to, say 15$ a month? assuming you have a single large table and <1000 users.

Comment: I don't how "large" the table is, but if you create an instance `db-f1-micro` with only 10 GB of SSD, the estimate is $9.37 per month and also disabling the automatic backups since those also cost. Anyway, you may need to test the instance if it works well with your load.  Also there are other costs like network usage.

Comment: Thanks very much, I read the docs again and just spoke with them , where can I read  more and evaluate more precisely how many users or actions MORE OR LESS I can have with the minimal 9$ a month ? Also - Google only allow me to choose 100G SSD, I can't do the 10G.  So are you basically say they almost don't care about users and queries, but mainly on the working instance, and a little about storage ?

Comment: Also I can't choose less than 3.75 memory ( and not less than 100G SSD) when I try to edit my instance.

Comment: You can change the disk size when creating the DB. Once it is created, the disk size cannot be changed :/ https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/instance-settings#storage-capacity-2ndgen. There is no doc on how much load the instance can handle and depends on every use case, so you need to benchmark it with your own tests.

Comment: When editing the instance in the `Machine Type` section, there is a dropdown menu and there you need to select `Shared core`. For the others (Lightweight, Standard & High Memory) the min is 3.75 GB

Comment: thanks a lot, yea I figure it all out yesterday. The only thing I try to learn is what type of "pressure" can a 1vcpu and 0.6G can handle.

Comment: This is a great answer. I had the same issue. I made two instances, 4 CPUs. I also thought it was priced by usage. I was being charged 1000 per month. They refunded me.

Comment: no matter what you choose, I have tried it all, SQL is quite expensive in GCLOUD.

Comment: Can someone share the process to delete the instances created? I don't want the instance I created accidentally!

Comment: @BilalSaeed please ask your specific question in a separate post

Comment: @Puteri same question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74496090/deleted-cloud-sql-instance-and-still-get-charged). Unfortunately, the answer of this question (link I shared) is also referring to this page here where solution to delete the instance is not given.

Comment: @BilalSaeed the question you linked is asking about why the charges you got for Cloud SQL so the comment was about explaining that. You never in your original question asked how to delete a Cloud SQL instance in the first place so ask a question in a different post about how to delete a cloud sql instance as I mentioned before. Also the question in this post is not about how to delete an instance so what you ask is out of scope of the post and the answer